# Rest Api Support for Deleting an Airflow Dag

Tags: java, rest, airflow, http-delete

After migration from airflow version 1.10.9 to 1.10.13rc1
The Rest API for Deleting a dag doesnt seem to Work
The Rest API I am using is  :
curl --location --request DELETE '/api/experimental/dags/<dag_id>'
I get a 404 error response for this , the Documents do not specify any particular API for deleting Dags

Comment: Do you intend to delete DAG from `dag` table or delete the actual DAG file?

Comment: delete from dag table